# Divs not showing up when hosted on a website

Tags: css, html

Locally the progress bars shows up. but when hosted it only shows the percentage text.

So far when hosted locally everything works fine but I can't seem to find the problem when hosting it on a website, no errors are given either.

I'd like it to show up when I'm actually visiting the website. But for now it shows only the text between the span tags.

Inline css and seperate .css file.

```css
#skills{
width:100%; 
height:20px; 
border:1.2px 
solid black;
}

#HTML {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #c5e5ef;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#PHP {
  width: 71%;
  background-color: #c5e5ef;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#MySQL {
  width: 66%;
  background-color: #c5e5ef;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#CSS {
  width: 88%;
  background-color: #c5e5ef;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#Java {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #c5e5ef;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>HTML</p>
<div id="skills">
  <div id="HTML"><span style="color: black;"><b>90%</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>PHP</p>
<div id="skills">
  <div id="PHP"><span style="color: black;"><b>71%</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>MySQL</p>
<div id="skills">

  <div id="MySQL"><span style="color: black;"><b>66%</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>CSS</p>
<div id="skills">

  <div id="CSS"><span style="color: black;"><b>88%</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>Java</p>
<div id="skills">
  <div id="Java"><span style="color: black;"><b>45%</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it sounds like you forgot to upload your css, but it's hard to tell without seeing the hosted instance.

Comment: css is uploaded with the rest of my files. It's like as if it just completely ignores a part.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page that's not working?

Comment: It is working apperently, I used my phone to go to the website and eveything was there only on my laptop those divs aren't showing up. I'd rather not post my personal website here. At least it's working, I guess my chrome history might have messed with it.

Comment: What you are showing is so much incomplete to evaluate that it does not make any sense to ask for help.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: sounds to me like a caching problem

Comment: Code is fixed, well it wasn't really the code but more some divs I did not close propely on the right line. But thanks anyways for your comments!

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know how this site works. You'll need to accept an answer, provide and accept your own, or delete this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly just a browser caching issue, as it seems to work in the code snippet you included above.

To avoid this kind of issues in the future, try developing the habit of refreshing using Ctrl+F5 while changing HTML & CSS code in your web pages, which forces the browser to redownload and parse your page.

Just a note: you should be using Classes to assign CSS to your Div blocks instead, and ID attributes should be unique, as they're generally used in JavaScript to retrieve and manipulate the contents of said blocks